# Redirect input from a file to a program

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to write a program that can read input from a file, and got stuck.
my program is  prog:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$(($1 + $2))
echo $num
```

my input test.in:

```
1
1
```

I used

```
./prog < test1.in
```

but got error message
./prog: line 2: + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")

What's wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome.  What are some troubleshooting steps that you've already tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have written is not a program that reads input from a file, but a program that takes its input in the form of *positional parameters* (aka command-line arguments). The redirection operator `<` sends your file data to the program's *standard input stream* (aka `stdin`) - which your program ignores.

At its simplest, to read one line per value from standard input, you could change your program to

```
#!/bin/bash
read a
read b
num=$((a+b))
echo $num
```

Now when you redirect `stdin` from your test file, the result should be

```
$ ./newprog < test1.in
2
```

Alternatively you could have used the `xargs` utility to read your file data and pass its contents to your program as arguments

```
$ xargs -a test1.in ./prog
2
```

Answer (score 1):

The program you wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$(($1 + $2))
echo "$num"
```

Expects the values of `$1` and `$2` (which are positional arguments) to be supplied in the list of the arguments to the program (script).
To get such program working, you need to call it like:

```
$ ./prog 3 5 
8
```

Placing each argument `$1` and `$2` in the calling command line.

---

If you require a program that reads the input from a file, you need to use read:

```
#!/bin/bash
read var1
read var2
num=$((var1 + var2))
echo "$num"
```

Then, you call it like:

```
$ ./newprog < test1.in
2
```